# Frobenius Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, frobenius-method, frobenius-groups

> Let a[1],...,a[n] be positive integer such that gcd(a[1],...,a[n])=1 and a[1]<...< a[n]
>   how can find number such that "***Max*** number of representable is 1 in linear combination" for example :

a[1]=7 ; a[2]=11 ; a[3]=13 => 45

3*7+1*11+1*13=45

**unique representable**

I'm looking for a formula for that

Code Python for find number

```
def builtin_gcd(a,b):
      for p in range(1,a+1):
            if a%p==0 and b%p==0:
                  t=p
      return t

def gcd(a, *r):
      for b in r:
            a = builtin_gcd(a, b)
      return a

def H(n,L):
      'L::list'
      if n==0:
            return 0
      aa=int(n/L[0])
      bb=int(n/L[1])
      cc=int(n/L[2])
      s=0
      for a in range(aa+1):
            for b in range(bb+1):
                  for c in range(cc+1):
                        if a*L[0]+b*L[1]+c*L[2]==n:
                              s+=1
      return(s)
def find(List):
      if gcd(*List)!=1 :
            return("Error GCD: the gcd of the given list should be number 1 but is %d"%gcd(*List)) 
      a=List[0]*List[1]-List[0]-List[1]
      for i in range(a+1,0,-1):
            if H(i,List)==1:
                  return i

find([7,11,13])=45
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are looking for. What does the number $45$ represent in connection with $[7,11,13]$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I think OP wants the largest integer that has exactly one representation as a positive integer linear combination of the given $a[i]$.

Comment: hi Unfortunately, I can't write English very well

Comment: this is my frobenius problem job, I want to achieve significant results through a unique show, One of the important proofs for the two numbers (which is solved) is the unique display, For more information, you can read the book diophanti frobenius problem,I have translated this text using google translate

Comment: It can be proved that the  number of views from one place to another is not unique That is more than one

Comment: If you need other programming codes like java ,c#, maple ,pari gp, Order to send

Comment: gerry myerson is right